# multiple Namespace support in AKS with AGIC

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, ingress-controller, aad-pod-identity

I am following the instruction to enable multiple Namespace support in an AKS with AGIC.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-multiple-namespace-support

**Step 1** - Install AAD Pod Identity on the default namespace (one time in a cluster)

> kubectl apply -f
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/master/deploy/infra/deployment-rbac.yaml

> serviceaccount/aad-pod-id-nmi-service-account unchanged
> customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/azureassignedidentities.aadpodidentity.k8s.io
> configured
> customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/azureidentities.aadpodidentity.k8s.io
> configured
> customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/azureidentitybindings.aadpodidentity.k8s.io
> configured
> customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/azurepodidentityexceptions.aadpodidentity.k8s.io configured
> clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aad-pod-id-nmi-role unchanged
> clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aad-pod-id-nmi-binding unchanged
> daemonset.apps/nmi configured
> serviceaccount/aad-pod-id-mic-service-account unchanged
> clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aad-pod-id-mic-role unchanged
> clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aad-pod-id-mic-binding unchanged

**Step 2** - Install "application gateway Kubernetes ingress" per namespace in the cluster. Here is the part of helm-config.yaml file which is used with helm install.

> ```
> # Specify the authentication with Azure Resource Manager
> #
> # Two authentication methods are available:
> # - Option 1: AAD-Pod-Identity (https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity)
> armAuth:
>     type: aadPodIdentity
>     identityResourceID: <identityResourceId>
>     identityClientID:  <identityClientId>
>
> # Specify aks cluster related information. THIS IS BEING DEPRECATED.
> aksClusterConfiguration:
>     apiServerAddress: <aks-api-server-address>
> ```

I want to know, how do I get the values to be set for *identityResourceId*, *identityClientId* and *aks-api-server-address*